# How does the new Xdebug 3 configuration work?

Tags: php, xdebug, ini

In Xdebug 2 I'm using this configuration:

```
; Do not show Xdebug "enhanced" error messages:
xdebug.default_enable = 0

; Start debugging when XDEBUG_SESSION cookie comes in:
xdebug.remote_enable=1

; Start a profile when XDEBUG_PROFILE cookie comes in:
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
```

How does this translate to the new Xdebug 3 config format?

I tried

```
xdebug.mode = debug,profile
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
```

but it starts debugging when profiling is desired. (Which might be a bug?)

Edit to clarify: Of course I don't want to debug and profile *at the same time*, just switch between them using Xdebug helper:

[image: Xdebug helper]

Comment: `xdebug.mode = debug,profile` -- this makes no sense to me. I mean: profiling usually means measuring execution speed ... while debugging will produce delays (stopping at the breakpoint, getting context values to your IDE etc) and therefore will provide incorrect values for profiling. They are not that compatible in that sense. Docs say that `xdebug.start_with_request=trigger` will work for whatever mode is selected .. but you have got 2 of them listed there... You can try swapping the order (`profile,debug`) but I don't think it will make any difference here TBH.

Comment: @LazyOne Of course I wouldn't profile and debug at the same time (Xdebug helper doesn't even allow that), but I think they must both be enabled in php.ini to be able to use both functions at runtime?

Comment: You switch between them when needed (by editing that value) -- that's how I understand it. From Xdebug's author own blog post 2 years ago https://derickrethans.nl/xdebug-experience.html -- *"and a few that **should never be used together** (xdebug.remote_enable and xdebug.profiler_enable)."* P.S. I see you have reported that alredy -- https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1915 -- will be checking that to see what Derick will say.

Comment: @LazyOne `profiler_enable_trigger` != `profiler_enable`

Comment: I know that as I have been using it in the same way  (last time that was about 1 year ago though). I've mentioned that to show that there is general problem in this field and it is *possible* that it may have been implemented this way on purpose (so that you *have* to choose between the 2...)

Comment: From https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1915 : "This is fixed on GitHub for Xdebug 3.0.2 now. I would like to mention that having both the debugger and profiler on at the same time will result in less accurate profiles due to the overhead that having the debugger enabled will cause. This overhead is there whether the debugger is activated (through the trigger) or not. I would not advice you to have the debugger as part of "xdebug.mode" in case you want accurate profiles. cheers, Derick "

Answer (score 2):

```
xdebug.mode = debug,profile
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
```

Works fine for me, and it launches only the operation requested with Xdebug helper, without launching the other.

Comment: Yes, this has been fixed: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1915